# How to get past 6 days data in Django?

Tags: django

I have a variable `reg_date`and `devc`.
I want to get the `total number of devc` in the past 6 days.

I have these code in views.py

```
todays_date = datetime.now()
past_six_days = todays_date - 6  ## I'm afraid if i do like this, I will get negative number when todays_date is 1/11/2018
```

How can I get the total number of device where 'reg_date' is inside the 'past_six_days' range ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your model is called `Device` it would be something like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now()
six_days_ago_date = (today - timedelta(days=6)).date()
Device.objects.filter(reg_date__gte=six_days_ago_date)  # all devices from past 6 days
```